# perl eval() gives 'Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch' on string variable

Tags: perl

The variables $var and $var2 in the following code hold same value but behave differently with respect to eval().

Source:

```
use Data::Dumper; 

sub trim($)
{
    my $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;    
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    $string =~ s/\R//g;
    return $string;
}

my $var2="";
$var2.="{id=>1962}";
$var2.=",{id=>1645}";
$var2.=",{id=>905}";
$var2.=",{id=>273}";
$var2.=",{id=>1800}";
$var2.=",{id=>21}";
$var2.=",{id=>1639}";
$var2.=",{id=>55}";
$var2.=",{id=>57}";
$var2.=",{id=>59}";
$var2.=",{id=>420}";
$var2.=",{id=>418}";
$var2="[".$var2."]";

print Dumper $var2;
print Dumper eval($var2); #evaluates to an ARRAY

my $filename = "sample.txt";
open(FILE, $filename) or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
$document = <FILE>; 
close (FILE);  
$document=trim($document);
@data = split(',', $document);     
my $var = "";
foreach my $val (@data) {
     $var.="{id=>".$val."},";               
}         
chop($var);
$var =  "[".$var."]";
print "\n";

if ($var eq $var2){
    print "var and var2 stringwise equal\n" ;
}else{
    print "var and var2 stringwise not equal\n" ;
}

print Dumper $var;
print Dumper eval($var); #error

exit(0);
```

Content of sample.txt:

```
1962,1645,905,273,1800,21,1639,55,57,59,420,418
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = '[{id=>1962},{id=>1645},{id=>905},{id=>273},{id=>1800},{id=>21},{id=>1639},{id=>55},{id=>57},{id=>59},{id=>420},{id=>418}]';
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'id' => 1962
          },
          {
            'id' => 1645
          },
          {
            'id' => 905
          },
          {
            'id' => 273
          },
          {
            'id' => 1800
          },
          {
            'id' => 21
          },
          {
            'id' => 1639
          },
          {
            'id' => 55
          },
          {
            'id' => 57
          },
          {
            'id' => 59
          },
          {
            'id' => 420
          },
          {
            'id' => 418
          }
        ];

var and var2 stringwise equal
$VAR1 = '[{id=>1962},{id=>1645},{id=>905},{id=>273},{id=>1800},{id=>21},{id=>1639},{id=>55},{id=>57},{id=>59},{id=>420},{id=>418}]';
Insecure dependency in eval while running with -T switch at assignment.pl line 51.
```

Can anyone tell why "eval($var)" doesn't get evaluated despite having same value as that of $var2 ?

Comment: A better question is: Why use eval at all? Everything you are doing here is quite redundant. Instead of building a large string that you eval into an array, just push the mini-hashes onto the array in the loop: `for my $val (@data) { push @array, { id => $val }; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perl [`Taint Mode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Taint-mode) doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing.  You're reading in data from an external resource, and perl -T is not allowing you to run tainted data through [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) since that literally could end up doing anything (very insecure).

In order to [`launder your data`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Laundering-and-Detecting-Tainted-Data) you simply need to run in through a regular expression to verify what it is.  Replace the following line:

```
#my @data = split(',', $document);     
my @data = $document =~ m/(\d+)/g;
```

Because we're running the external document data through a regex, the values in `@data` will no longer be [`tainted`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#How-can-I-tell-if-a-variable-is-tainted%3f) and can be `eval`'d.

Either way, I'd advise against using `eval` at all unless there is a specific reason why you need it.  The following accomplishes the same thing without the need for an `eval`

```
my $var = [map {id => $_}, @data];
```

Answer (score 2):

While `$var` might be the same as `$var2` in your specific case of data, it isn't necessarily always that case. You script also doesn't forbid the `eval` even if it is not the same.

Thus, the tainted check is right to complain about the insecure `eval`, as it is intended to detect potentially unsafe operations which your `eval($var)` definitely is.

Generally, you should try to avoid eval wherever you can, as it is a prime source of remote-code-execution vulnerabilities. Instead, you should try to parse your data structures using other, safer means, e.g. by using `split` on your input data and then looping over the resulting array to produce your desired data structure.